# How to pass large number arguments to **kwargs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe :

```
   p     p_loc  s            s0  s0_loc  s1  s1_loc  s2 s2_loc  s3   s3_loc
0  ABCD  M      AB,AC,AD     AB  A       AC   M      AD  Q      NaN  U
1  PQRS  N      PQ,PR,PS,QR  PQ  B       PR   N      PS  R      QR   V
```

I'm splitting column s into columns s0,s1,s2,s3 using , as delimeter.
I want to pass values from s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc,s3_loc to following function which accepts following arguments:

```
def func(p,p_loc,**args):
    print(p)
    print(p_loc)
    print(kwargs)
```

I'm passing arguments as follows:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(df['p'],df['p_loc'],df['s0'],df['s1'],df['s2'],df['s3'],df['s0_loc'],df['s1_loc'],df['s2_loc'],df['s3_loc']))
```

I want to know is there any simpler way to pass these arguments(Say, suppose my split of column s results in more than 15-20 columns.. How can I pass these many arguments in a simpler way)...???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you pass a list/tuple with those values in?

Comment: I want to know how many columns created by splitting column s based on ','. Then for those columns (say for s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5) I want to pass columns(s0_loc,1_loc,s2_loc,s3_loc,s4_loc,s5_loc) along with s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `set` of positional arguments like:

```
>>> not_kwargs = {'p', 'p_loc', 's'}
```

Next filter out kwargs like:

```
>>> data = df.to_dict()
>>> kwargs = {key:data[key] for key in data.keys() ^ not_kwargs}
```

If you are using [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), `^` only operates on `set`.

```
>>> kwargs = {key:data[key] for key in set(data.keys()) ^ not_kwargs}
```

Call function:

```
>>> func(data['p'], data['p_loc'], **kwargs)
```

Comment: everything works perfectly with this but I don't want to pass column 's' to the function. So is there a way to eliminate column s from kwargs

Comment: You don't want to pass column `s` at all?

Comment: should I create another set to remove the columns I want to exclude from kwargs??

Comment: yes... I don't want to pass column 's' to the function

Comment: Check my recent edits. The `set` will now contains keys that are to be excluded from kwargs.

Comment: I've tried with following and it worked:                                                   
excl_set = {'sec'}                                                                                                              kwargs = {key:df[key] for key in set(df.keys()) ^ pos_args ^ excl_set}

Comment: Yes this should work as well. You can use `^` operator with as many set as you want. Infact it is better to create separate set to manage excluded kwargs.

Comment: You're recent edit also worked well.. Thanks a lot... Can you also tell me following code snippet  is also right or wrong??                                  
excl_set = {'sec'}                                                                                                   kwargs = {key:df[key] for key in set(df.keys()) ^ pos_args ^ excl_set}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can put the columns you require in a seperate list and generate the arguments when you need them.

```
def func(p, p_loc, *args):
    print(p)
    print(p_loc)
    print(args)

list_of_cols = ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's0_loc', 's1_loc', 's2_loc','s3_loc']
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(df['p'], df['p_loc'], *[df[col] for col in list_of_cols]))
```

Comment: This is a roundabout way of doing it, and specifying columns as a list is a problem when you have too many of them.

Comment: i'm splitting column 's' using ',' as delimeter. The resultant columns after splitting may vary on different datasets. So I want a syntax without explicily mentioning the coulmn names... something using list/dictionary comprehensions

Comment: only for passing s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 and it's respective s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc,s3_loc,s4_loc,s5_loc columns

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

You can pass a dict into kwargs like this:

```
d = {
    'p': df['p'],
    'p_loc': df['p_loc'],
    's0': df['s0'],
    's1': df['s1'],
    ...
    }

def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

func(**d)
```

Comment: p and p_loc are required arguments for the function.                                    Is there any way to create a dictionary only for s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 and s0_loc,s1_loc,s2_loc,s3_loc,s4_loc,s5_loc such as using list comprehension.

Comment: because i'm splitting column 's' using ',' as delimeter. The resultant columns after splitting may vary on different datasets. So I want a syntax without explicily mentioning the coulmn names.

Comment: I was trying following:

Comment: maxlen = max(list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(",")) ,df.s)))

Comment: cols = ["sec"+str(x)   for x in range(maxlen)]

Comment: loc_cols = ["sec"+str(x)+"_loc"   for x in range(maxlen)]

Comment: Can you illustrate how to create a dictionary with something like this, so that there is no need of explicitly mentioning the newly created columns

Comment: d = {col: df[col] for col in df.columns.values}

Comment: can you add a full answer of invoking the function with this @Myles Hollowed